# How to return information from the parse function to the start_requests function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

This problem is starting to frustrate me very much as I feel like I have no clue how scrapy works and that I can't wrap my head around the documentation.

My question is simple. I have the most standard of spiders.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.spider):

    def start_requests(self):
        header = ..
        url = "www.website.whatever/search/filter1=.../&page=1"
        test =  scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers = header)

    def parse(self, response):
        site_number_of_pages = int(response.xpath(..))
        return site_number_of_pages
```

I just want to somehow get the number of pages from the parse function back into the start requests function so I can start a for loop to go through all the pages on the website, using the same parse function again. The code above does illustrated the principle only but would not work if put in practice. Variable `test` would be a `Request` class and not my plain Joe integer that I want.

How would I accomplish what I am trying to do?

EDIT:
This is what I have tried up till now

```
class MySpider(scrapy.spider):

    def start_requests(self):
        header = ..
        url = ..
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers = header)

    def parse(self, response):
        header = ..
        site_number_of_pages = int(response.xpath(..))
        for count in range(2,site_number_of_pages):
            url = url + str(count)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers = header)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is asynchronous framework. Here is no any possibility to.. return to `start_urls` - only Requests followed by it's callbacks.

On general case if Requests appeared as result of some response parsing (on your case - `site_number_of_pages` from first url) - it is not `start_requests`

The easiest thing You can do in this case - is to `yield` requests from `parse` method.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        site_number_of_pages = int(response.xpath(..))
        for i in range(site_number_of_pages):
            ...
            yield Request(url=...
```

Comment: i tried to call the parse function from within the parse function but it kept resetting the value of i. or maybe I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: @CristianCapsuna Can You provide complete spider code?

Comment: Hi Georgiy. I have added to the bottom of my post what I have tried before. that cause it to keep resetting the value of count which is understandable.

Comment: @CristianCapsuna I don't see any unexpected behaviour. You set `self.parse` as callback inside `parse` method. For each of page_url -> it will return requests the same requests from cycle.
I see following options:
1. Keep it 'As is' - by default scrapy dupefilter will block requests that leads to urls that app already scraped in this run.
2. set request.callack to another Spider method.

Comment: Hi Georgiy. When I was running that loop I was observing some pretty weird behaviour that I am not able to explain to due my limited understanding of scrapy. Example: 
 counter jumping between values that did not make much sense; it skipped scraping some pages. Your advice was useful in pushing me to try something else rather than keep trying to make it work. I will post the solution I found. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @CristianCapsuna  I don't think that scrapy skipping pages. Scrapy is not.. following sctrict order of requests by it's asynchronous design. For example it can return result of page9 before page3 in case of that requests returned from cycle (I agree that this behaviour is not obvious and It still confuse a lot of beginner scrapy users).

Comment: Hi Georgiy. That is very interesting. I had not thought of that. After completing this project I am working on I will experiment a bit. Need to know how the tool works to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grabbing the number of pages and looping through all of them, I grabbed the "next page" feature of the web page. So everytime `self.parse` is activated it will grab the next page and call itself again. This will go on until there is no next page and it will just error out.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.spider):

def start_requests(self):
    header = ..
    url = "www.website.whatever/search/filter1=.../&page=1"
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers = header)

def parse(self, response):
    header = ..
    ..
    next_page = response.xpath(..)
    url = "www.website.whatever/search/filter1=.../&page=" + next_page
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers = header)
```